# How to close jquery dialog upon form data upload completion

Tags: jquery, dialog

My form is posting text and files(images), this all works in the backend and I have no problems with this. Its posting to itself. (php)

I have created a jquery dialog that opens as the submit button is clicked. This shows that the files are uploading.

How can I close the dialogue upon errors or once the files/data have been uploaded?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({width: 400,autoOpen: false,hide: 'fade', show: 'fade', position: 'center', modal: 'true', closeOnEscape: true}); 
    $("#go").click(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog('open')
    });
    $("#hide").click(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog('close')
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be complete when the `$(body).load()` event is fired, but I'm not 100% on that